# Typescript: Any way to merge a local interface with an external one?

Tags: typescript

So I'm using the simple-peer Typescript definition as provided [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/simple-peer/index.d.ts). However, the definition is slightly out of date causing some Typescript errors to show when it would be valid if the definition were amended. I've submitted a pull request to fix these definitions, but in the mean time, I'm wondering if there's an easy way to correct the definition just at the top of my file?

I could of course just copy paste the whole definition into a new, local file and make the corrections in that, but was hoping for a more elegant solution. Something like:

```
import * as SimplePeer from "simple-peer";

interface SimplePeer.Options extends SimplePeer.Options{
    objectMode:boolean;
}
```

If this were valid Typescript, it would just merge that extra property onto the already existing definition for SimplePeer.Options. Is there a valid way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply be able to specify the new, additional properties of `SimplePeer.Options` without referencing the original. Typescript does [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), with one of the first examples being two interfaces:

```
interface Box {
    height: number;
    width: number;
}

interface Box {
    scale: number;
}

let box: Box = {height: 5, width: 6, scale: 10};
```

I use this heavily with Immutable to allow iteration over their collections, so it works well (as far as I know) with external libraries:

```
/* monkey-patch immutable to support es6 iteration */
declare module 'immutable' {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
  namespace Iterable {
    interface Indexed<T> {
      [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
    }

    interface Iterator<T> {
      [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
    }

    interface Keyed<K, V> {
      [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[K, V]>;
    }
  }
}
/* no more monkeys */
```

Comment: I have `import * as SimplePeer from "simple-peer";` at the top of my file, which Typescript reports as the problem: "Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'SimplePeer'"

Comment: That's not easily tested in the sandbox; does it work with `import {Options} from 'simple-peer';`? I exclusively use destructuring imports and have not had a problem, but it may depend on how the library is declared (which I'm looking into).

Comment: `export namespace SimplePeer{
 export interface Options{
  objectMode:boolean
 }
}` is valid but the Typescript error for the extra Options property is still there so I'm assuming it's not working